# Cannot move out of borrowed content with optional members passed as argument

Tags: memory, rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I have a `find` function defined on a basic in-memory storage solution. I'm trying to find a way to flexibly pass conditional search options by creating a `struct` called `SearchOpts`:

```
trait HasRecords {
    fn find(&self, opts: &SearchOpts) -> ();
}

pub struct SearchOpts {
    sensorId: Option<String>,
}

struct MemDb {
    id: u32,
}

impl HasRecords for MemDb {
    fn find(&self, opts: &SearchOpts) -> () {
        println!("Hello {}", opts.sensorId.unwrap());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _x = MemDb { id: 42 };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d3bcd340fafa93900ab30aeafffcb455&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:15:30
   |
15 |         println!("Hello {}", opts.sensorId.unwrap());
   |                              ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I don't know if this is the best way to implement this sort of functionality, but I also don't understand how to please the borrow checker in this instance (which is the thing I'd like to learn first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that since you only have a reference to the `SearchOpts` struct in your function, you can't move out of it.

Looking at the [definition of `Option::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap):

```
pub fn unwrap(self) -> T
```

It takes the `Option` argument by value, so it would move out of the struct. No good! The key to fixing this is `Option::as_ref`:

```
pub fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T>
```

As the signature implies, it transforms `&Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`. This latter type can be unwrapped (resulting in `&T`) without moving anything. So you can write:

```
if opts.sensorId.is_some() && &d.sensorId != opts.sensorId.as_ref().unwrap() {
     return false;
}
```

However, I would write it like this:

```
if opts.sensorId.as_ref().map_or(false, |id| id != &d.sensorId) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I get a different error since `d.sensorId` is now a different type to `opts.sensorId.as_ref().unwrap()`.

Comment: That's what I get for not testing sample code. We can just write `&d.sensorId` then. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Ok, that works now, thanks.

Comment: Surely the `map_or` conditional should be `!=` rather than `==`?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is.

Comment: Ah, must have misread, nvm.

Comment: I'd write `*id != d.sensorid`. It results in the same (to compare references, you have to compare the pointers), but it's more intuitive. Or even better write `|&id| id != d.sensorId)`

Comment: `*id != d.sensorId` works, but you can't do `|&id| id != d.sensorId` here -- that attempts to move out from the reference, defeating of purpose of using `as_ref`.